# Node / Express, including custom modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently using Express with node and I am running into an issue when trying to use a custom module from inside one of my route functions. Here is what I have so far.

In my app.js file I require the module like so.

```
c_controller = require( './core/c_controller' );
```

I know this is required correctly because I console logged it out and it shows up fine.

The c_controller module looks like this.

```
var c_controller = {

styles: [],
script: '',
view: ''
};

c_controller.add_style = function( style ) {

    this.styles.push( style );

    return this;
},

c_controller.set_script = function( script ) {

    this.script = script;

    return this;
},

c_controller.set_view = function( view ) {

    this.view = view;

    return this;
},

c_controller.render = function() {

    return { script: this.script,
             styles: this.styles,
             view: this.view };
}

exports.add_style = c_controller.add_style;
exports.set_script = c_controller.set_script;
exports.set_view = c_controller.set_view;
exports.render = c_controller.render;
```

The error that appears is 500 ReferenceError: c_controller is not defined.

Now im not sure if I have to pass the c_controller object into my route functions, either way im not sure how to do this.

I anyone could explain this to me to make it clearer that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

Here is the code that uses the c_controller

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */
exports.index = function(req, res){

    c_controller.set_view( 'index' );

    res.render( 'includes/overall_template', { c_controller.render() } );
};
```

Now if I require the c_controller directly into the route it works. I would rather only require the module in the main app file so I will not have to do this in every route. Does anyone know if this is possible??

Comment: show us the code that uses `c_controller`? The offending line, the one saying `ReferenceError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try and summarize all the comments, and what you yourself @DavidJones said:

1. From within your custom view, `c_controller` is not known. You would have to either `require` it in the view's module or even in the view function itself. You could also pass it to the view class, but I that complicates thing, and much prefer requiring.
2. What @Linus said -- think about exporting your whole object (not just the function), or use `bind` otherwise.

Comment: Hi, I am going to go the direction of requiring it directly into the route. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great. If this solved your problem feel free to upvote/accept.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `this` inside your functions in `c_controller` and you then assign only the functions to the export object, your functions will reference `export` when you write `this` and **not** `c_controller`.

I think the best way to fix it is to export the entire `c_controller` object, like this:

```
module.exports = exports = c_controller;
```

If you want the `styles`, `script` and `view` variables hidden you can either:

1. Use `c_controller` instead of `this`
2. Bind the functions before exporting them, like so: `exports.add_style = c_controller.add_style.bind(c_controller)`

Comment: @DavidJones seems like this might not be the actual problem you are facing, but you'll probably run in to it when you fix your current problem. Is the code that uses `c_controller` in the same file as `c_controller = require('c_controller');`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this was the way I originally did it, but I read a article that did separate exports on each function, I have changed it back and it works fine now I require it directly into the route. I can live with that so its cool. Thanks for the help.